# How do you input a real number?

Tags: dictionary, input, numbers, int, coordinates

How do I enter a real number in to python as this:

```
lat = int(input("Enter Location Latitude"))
```

returns a syntax error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Ryan/Desktop/km map.py", line 1, in <module>
    lat = int(input("Enter Location Latitude"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '52.63529'
```

I need to enter a longitude and latitude coordinates into this program and with that I need to add and take away 0.01862 to this input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
lat = float(input("Enter Location Latitude"))
```

When you are typing numbers with decimal parts you have to use floating point number formats.